# HTML button don't submit

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this HTML code in a JSP page, but when I click it does not do anything

```
<button class="btn btn-grey" type="submit">Save device</button>
```

Comment: I feel there isn't enough code to support the question. However, have a look at your console and check for errors in the meantime.

Comment: I think you will have to provide more code (or perhaps your page is lacking this). The button should be surrounded with `<form>` tags like for instance `<form action="main.jsp" method="GET">`.

Comment: and if "php" is involved, you should also let us know, seeing someone posted an answer below using a post method in form.

Comment: Only HTML can't do anything. You need to use script to get behavior from this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Amadeu Cabanilles,

You have to put your button into form.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="modelName" action="/submitSomeWhere">

    <button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-primary pull- right">Update</button>

</form>
```

Comment: indeed, was out of the <form> tag

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper form tags in your html , correct form post should be :

```
 <form id="createMarkerForm" 
    method="post" 
    accept-charset="utf-8" 
    action="servletUrl">
```